# Equivalence between K-Means objective functions proof

Tags: optimization, unsupervised-learning, k-means

I am working on a project involving the K-Means clustering algorithm, and I am trying to prove the equivalence between different formulations of the objective function. Specifically, I want to show the equivalence between the original objective function:

$$ \arg \min_{\{\mathcal{D}_k\}, \{\boldsymbol{\mu}_k\}} \sum_{k=1}^{K} \sum_{\boldsymbol{x}_i \in \mathcal{D}_k} \|\boldsymbol{x}_i - \boldsymbol{\mu}_k\|_2^2
$$

and two alternative formulations:

1. $$\arg \min_{\{\mathcal{D}_k\}} \sum_{k=1}^{K} \frac{1}{|\mathcal{D}_k|} \sum_{\boldsymbol{x}_i, \boldsymbol{x}_j \in \mathcal{D}_k} \|\boldsymbol{x}_i - \boldsymbol{x}_j\|_2^2 $$
2. $$\arg \min_{\{\boldsymbol{\mu}_k\}} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \min_{k} \|\boldsymbol{x}_i - \boldsymbol{\mu}_k\|_2^2$$

where:

- $\mathcal{D}_k$ represents the (k)th cluster, which contains a subset of the data points
- $\mathcal{\mu}_k$ represents the (k)th centroid.

I have been struggling to prove the equivalence between these formulations. I have attempted expanding the expressions and rearranging terms, but I haven't been able to establish the desired equivalence.

Could someone provide guidance on how to demonstrate the equivalence between these objective functions? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!